# A way to achieve UISearchController appearance similar to Photos app in iOS 11

Tags: ios, uisearchcontroller, ios11

I would like to update my old iOS 10 application's `UISearchController` appearance to have effect similar to native **Photos app in iOS 11**. 
But I am not sure how to get such smooth animation of `NavigationBar` transition from `LargeTitle` to `UISearchController`.

**UPDATE**

I know that there is `UINavigationItem`'s property `UISearchController`, but it just shows `UISearchBar` **under the Large Title** and its appearance with `hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation` set to `true` looks completely different.

[image]

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: you can create a new controller & push without animation when user tap on search bar.

Comment: Do you mean to push UISearchController or just another UIViewController? However I've tried both options, and without animation NavigationBar just jumps. When animation is on, there is visible line, that goes right to left while pushing.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 11 there's a new way to add the `UISearchController` to the `UINavigationItem`. Check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/2897305-searchcontroller) from Apple.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, added update in the post with the response

Comment: @Sander it appears under the large title, but once you tap on it it goes all the way to the top just like the gif that you posted.

Comment: I know, but in Photos app, there is no Search bar under the large title.